# What is happening to my string literals?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, string-literals, atmega

Using GNU cc 4.8.1 to compile for Atmega64. My string literals are disappearing. I'm trying to push a frame out of the Atmega64 UARt and all of the frame makes it out except the payload (10 bytes in the middle) that come from a global array. If I write to the global array

```
array[0] = 'H';
array[1] = 'e';
array[2] = 'l';
array[3] = 'l';
array[4] = 'o';
```

this makes it out of the UART. However if I use a string literal `char *array = "Hello";` and then pass this pointer to memcpy(), this text never shifts out of the UART, though the header/footer portions of the frame do. I just get garbage where the payload/message should be. What is happening to the string literal, is the compiler just blowing it away for some reason? I fill the array in one function, then immediately call another function that builds the UART frame, copying the global array contents into the output array.

Here is my function to copy the string literal into a global array.

```
char screen[4][11]

display(void)
{
    char *strpt;

    LCDmemcpy(1, "stuff");  //doesn't work
    strpt = "blah";
    LCDmemcpy(2, strpt); //doesn't work either
}

void LCDmemcpy(char seg, char *buff)
{
    u8 i;

//  if(seg<5 && seg>0)
    {   
        //memcpy(&screen[seg-1][0], buff, 11);
        for(i=0; i<11; i++)
        {
            screen[seg-1][i] = buff[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `array` allocated?  If like this:  `char array[10]`, that assignment is misleading.  It would help to see a minimal version of your program.

Comment: Try looking at the assembler output and linker map.

Comment: in C, an array name degrades to the address of the array.  Strings cannot be copied via a simple assignment statement, that only copies a pointer to the array.   To actually copy the array, use memcpy().  The string functions would always insert a NUL byte into the array, and since your example does not insert the trailing NUL byte,  the memcpy() would be the best option.

Comment: I was a bit sloppy in my description. It would be lengthy to summarize everything I have tried. I've tried `char ptr[] = "hello"`, `const char ptr[] = "hello"`, passing the literal into a function such as `mycpy("hello")` with `void mycpy(char *ptr) {blah}` where blah is variously 'memcpy(dst, src, len)` or a for loop doing the same thing

Comment: The global array is `unsigned char array[x][y] = {0x20, 0x20,...};`
I am not actually assigning a string literal directly to a char[], but usually to char *. Or sometimes I just try to pass a literal to a function such as `mycpy(char *ptr)` Then immediately next I'll have `array[2][1] = '5';` and that one character will transfer out of the UART, but the preceding line where I try to transfer the string literal to the array doesn't work, except sometimes. I have a large else if like `if(x=1) {mycpy("hello"); else if(x=2) {mycpy("AAGH");}` and so on. For some cases the string literal works.

Comment: perhaps the problem of not passing the first array line is because in C an array index starts at 0 (not 1) and ends at arrayLen-1

Comment: Well its a little sloppy (i'm refactoring old code in pieces) but i decrement the first array index, so 1-4 maps to 0-3.

Comment: You don't check the length of the "buff" string. In your example, both values are under the "11" characters size you're trying to copy. That could explain the garbage you get.

Answer (score 0):

The name of an array decays to a pointer to the first element when used as a parameter in a function call. This would allow assignment of the literal (which decays to the same type) to it, which does not modify the original array (as the pointer is passed by value) but the value of the pointer parameter...

*This code illustrates your problem:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

void confusing(char array[])
{
    char* literal = "Hallo";
    array = literal;
    printf("%s - now array points to literal...not...\n", array);
}

int main(void) 
{
    char myArray[] = "xyz";
    confusing(myArray);
    printf("%s - as expected, no change here\n", myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hallo - now array points to literal...not...
xyz - as expected, no change here
```

Comment: I updated the my question. I'm not reassigning the pointer in the function. Just dereferencing it to assign its value to the global array. The literal is created in a function, passed to the LCDmemcpy() function,

Comment: Why is screen const. When I compile your code, I get a compiler error...assignment of read-only location

Comment: Good question. Its actually not, I typed it wrong. Corrected now in the original question.